# AWS Deployment fails for multi container deployment in Elastic Beanstalk docker type environment

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I chose environment type docker while creating elastic bean instance. Please find my Dockerrun.aws.json file. Can someone please find whats wrong here..  the error says the ELB processes are not healthy.

**Error**: Below is the error that I see after deployment
[image]

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
      "name": "db",
      "image": "library/postgres:12.3-alpine",
      "essential": true,
      "memory": 128,
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_USER",
          "value": "username"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
          "value": "password"
        },
        {
          "name": "POSTGRES_DB",
          "value": "plot-booking-system"
        }
      ],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 5434,
          "containerPort": 5432
        }
      ]
    },
      {
        "name": "client",
        "image": "sawansamal/plot-booking-ui:version5.0",
        "hostname": "client",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 300,
        "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "containerPort": 5000
        }
      ]
      },
      {
        "name": "backend",
        "image": "sawansamal/plot-booking-app:version12.0",
        "hostname": "backend",
        "essential": true,
        "memory": 500,
        "links": ["db"],
        "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8081,
          "containerPort": 8081
        }
      ]
      }
    ]
}
```

EDIT:
Adding docker compose file also doesn't help.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
volumes:
  data:
networks:
  plot-booking-network:
services:
  postgresql:
    image: library/postgres:12.3-alpine
    container_name: postgresql-15
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=plot-booking-system
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/postgresql-15-data
    ports:
      - 5434:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U username"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - plot-booking-network
  plot-Booking-app:
    image: sawansamal/plot-booking-app:version12.0
    ports:
      - "8080:5000"
    networks:
      - plot-booking-network
    depends_on:
      postgresql:
        condition: service_healthy
  plot-Booking-ui:
    image: sawansamal/plot-booking-ui:version5.0
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes: 
      - /app
      - /app/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
    networks:
      - plot-booking-network
    depends_on:
      - plot-Booking-app
```

Comment: These days docer-compose would be used for multi-container on EB. Any reason you used the old technology?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the quick reply. Docker compose also fails.. I have added the docker-compose.yml file.. Could you please check once.